# Laptop reboots when lid closed and unplugged

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop

Kubuntu 16.04 on Dell XPS13

Instead of suspending, when I close the lid and unplug the AC adapter (regardless of whether it's already unplugged when closing the lid, or I unplug it after, or if I plug it in before reopening) the computer reboots instead of suspending. When I reopen the lid, I see the computer booting up (I do not have to hit the power button as I would if the computer powered off).

This has happened before and then disappeared and come back etc etc. I started keeping track of packages I installed/upgraded and then testing but it's come back without me having made any change to the OS. I'm out of ideas for how to debug. The settings in power settings are all correct and I tried uncommenting `HandleLidSwitch=suspend` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` as well.

This is very frustrating, causes me to lose data, and has turned my laptop into a desktop effectively.

```
> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: Try this: https://wiki.debian.org/SystemdSuspendSedation

Comment: @MarkJ.Adams HandleLidSwitch was already uncommented, I tried also uncommenting HandleLidSwitchDocked and setting it to suspend and restarting login, but it has had no effect. When I close the lid and unplug it still reboots.

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/898517/closing-lid-problem or more https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#ACPI_events

Comment: None of those change anything. I'll note, also, that if I manually suspend (by using the application launcher), it unsuspends as normal regardless of whether I'm plugged in or not. There's something particular about the lid closing.