# HDMI monitor stops working when lap top lid is closed

Tags: multiple-monitors, power-management, hdmi

I have an HDMI monitor attached to my Ubuntu laptop and I usually work with my laptop lid closed.

For some reason suddenly the setup stopped working.

Now when I close the lid the external monitor screen goes black like there's no signal, but the system is not suspending nor hibernating because when I open the lid everything starts from where I left off (no login screen).

[image: dconf editor settings]

`journalctl -b -0` output:

```
...skipping...
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x60.0   81.62  1152 1216 1336 1520  864 865 868 895 -hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz e)
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0  119.00  1600 1696 1864 2128  900 901 904 932 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x75.0  220.64  1920 2056 2264 2608  1080 1081 1084 1128 -hsync +vsync (84.6 kHz e)
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 300000KHz
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym ff53 with keysym ff53 (keycode 72).
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym ff51 with keysym ff51 (keycode 71).
sep 23 14:28:04 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 6f with keysym 6f (keycode 20).
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude systemd-logind[1049]: Lid opened.
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Allocate new frame buffer 2560x1080 stride
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "GSM", prod id 30484
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2560x1080"x0.0  181.25  2560 2608 2640 2720  1080 1083 1093 1111 +hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz eP)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2560x1080"x0.0  228.25  2560 2608 2640 2720  1080 1083 1093 1119 +hsync -vsync (83.9 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2560x1440"x0.0  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x480"x0.0   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (56.2 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1720 1760 1980  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (37.5 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x576"x0.0   27.00  720 732 796 864  576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync (31.2 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x60.0   81.62  1152 1216 1336 1520  864 865 868 895 -hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0  119.00  1600 1696 1864 2128  900 901 904 932 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x75.0  220.64  1920 2056 2264 2608  1080 1081 1084 1128 -hsync +vsync (84.6 kHz e)
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2304]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 300000KHz
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym ff53 with keysym ff53 (keycode 72).
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym ff51 with keysym ff51 (keycode 71).
sep 23 14:29:16 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 6f with keysym 6f (keycode 20).
sep 23 14:29:17 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym ff53 with keysym ff53 (keycode 72).
sep 23 14:29:17 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym ff51 with keysym ff51 (keycode 71).
sep 23 14:29:17 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 6f with keysym 6f (keycode 20).
sep 23 14:29:19 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym ff53 with keysym ff53 (keycode 72).
sep 23 14:29:19 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym ff51 with keysym ff51 (keycode 71).
sep 23 14:29:19 ag_latitude org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2486]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 6f with keysym 6f (keycode 20).
```

Comment: After opening lid type `dmesg` for device messages. Then type `journalctl -b -0` for system messages. Press the `End` key to move to most recent messages. Press the `Q` key to exit system messages.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix added the log in the main question

Comment: So at `14:28` you closed the lid and `14.29` you opened the lid?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix correct

Comment: I'm heading out just now, but added an answer with something to try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Closing lid problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898517/closing-lid-problemFrom):

---

To make Ubuntu do nothing when laptop lid is closed:
Open the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file in a text editor as root, for example

`sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`

Add a line `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`

Restart the systemd daemon with this command:

`sudo service systemd-logind restart`

If that didn't work set the following

`IgnoreLid=true` in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

Comment: `IgnoreLid=true` in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` worked, I don't think it's a definitive solution but it does the job for now.